# Change text color to row clicked and keep it in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

when the user click a row in TableView the text color changes.

My question is how to keep in memory the row clicked and when come back to TableView to have the row with the new color?

This is in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSAttributedString * redString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:cell.textLabel.text];

NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:redString];

NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(0, redString.length);

[attributedString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-LightItalic" size:15.0] range:boldedRange];

[attributedString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor redColor] range:boldedRange];

[cell.textLabel setAttributedText: attributedString];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest keeping an `NSMutableDictionary` in your `UITableViewController` that keeps track of what cells have been selected. You can then update the dictionary whenever a cell is selected using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPaht:`

Example

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    NSIndexPath *idxKey = [NSIndexPath indexForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
    self.myMutableDictionary[idxKey] = @YES;
}
```

It might seem odd that you have to create an `NSIndexPath` given that one is provided in the method signature. The problem is, sometimes it is actually a mutable index path and will fail. By creating a copy this way you guarantee it is a non-mutable key.

Once you have your dictionary all you need to do is check the dictionary in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and see if it has been selected.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *idxKey = [NSIndexPath indexForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
    id value = self.myMutableDictionary[idxKey];
    if(value){
      // Set color selected
     } else {
      // Set color not selected
    } 
}
```